# Putting ScrollView and bottom menu on the same view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

The layout I'm trying to put `ScrollView` above of the menu at the bottom of the screen (which is just an `<include>` wrapped in `<LinearLayout>`.

**Problem: `ScrollView` doesn't work** (last elements of it cannot be shown on the screen and is show "below" the menu, which looks like there was no `ScrollView` at all) and **I can't scroll through it.**

**Layout .xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >
                <com.myapp.AutoResizeTextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_discounts_month"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic1"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:maxLines="100"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/label1"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_discounts_month_number"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/text_discounts_month"
                    android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:minEms="2"
                    android:text="@string/label1_number"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- Horizontal line -->
            <View
                android:id="@+id/hr1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/l1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
<!-- There are many more items as the item below inside the layout, i.e. LinearLayout followed by a horizontal line -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
<!-- Bottom menu -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <include
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/menu_bottom_full" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use layout_weight property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/down"
        android:fillViewport="true" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg" >
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >
```

Try this